# Extracting a smaller Markov chain from a larger Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am not very familiar with Markov chains, hence the probably ill titled questions.

If we have 5 random variables $X, Y, Z, W$ and they form a Markov chain such that

$$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W \rightarrow P$$

Is also the case that

$$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow P$$
or 
$$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow W $$

Intuitively I would assume it is true because no information about $X$ can be gained as we move along the chain, thus it is okay to remove a link.

Secondly if i recall correctly then if $Z = f(Y)$ then $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain. So in my example $f$ is just a composite function.

This is obviously a weak understanding at best, so any help is appreciated.

Edit:
My understanding is that 3 random variables $X, Y, Z$ form a markov chain if $X$ and $Z$ and conditionally independent given $Y$. So
$$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \iff p(x, y, z)=p(x) p(y | x) p(z | y)$$

Comment: what is $X-Y$ ?

Comment: it's just meant to be $\leftrightarrow$. it could even be $\rightarrow$ as well to my understanding. I will update the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Are $X,Y,\ldots$ states or random variables? What does $X\to Y$ mean if they are random variables? If it means $Y$ takes the value of $X$, how are your three chains compatible?

Comment: @Chrystomath Updated the question. I hope it answers the question.

Comment: The arrows $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ represent conditional relationships, it means the conditional distribution of $Z$, given $Y$, is independent of $X$.  Indeed you can remove a link as you conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show you can remove one link (then you can recursively remove as many as you like). Suppose: 
$$ X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W$$
You want to show 
$$ X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow W$$

For simplicity assume all random variables are discrete and let $S_X, S_Y, S_Z, S_W$ be the finite or countably infinite sets of all possible values these variables can take (with positive probability).

Then for all $w \in S_W, x \in S_X, y \in S_Y$ we have 
\begin{align}
&P[X=x, Y=y,W=w] \\
&\overset{(a)}{=} \sum_{z \in S_Z} P[X=x, Y=y, Z=z, W=w]\\
&\overset{(b)}{=}\sum_{z \in S_Z} P[X=x]P[Y=y|X=x]P[Z=z|Y=y]P[W=w|Z=z]\\
&= P[X=x]P[Y=y|X=x]\sum_{z \in S_Z} P[W=w|Z=z]P[Z=z|Y=y]\\
&\overset{(c)}{=}P[X=x]P[Y=y|X=x]\sum_{z \in S_Z} P[W=w|Z=z, Y=y]P[Z=z|Y=y]\\
&=P[X=x]P[Y=y|X=x]P[W=w|Y=y]
\end{align}
where (a) is from the law of total probability; (b) and (c) use the Markov chain assumption $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W$.

Comment: I don't see why (c) follows from the definition of markov chain. Indeed, the definition says $\mathbb{P}(W=w | X=x, Y=y, Z=z) = \mathbb{P}(W=w | Z=z)$.

Comment: I am claiming $P[W=w|Z=z]=P[W=w|Z=z, Y=y]$ since $Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W$. If you want you can sum out the $x$ variable: $$P[W=w|Z=z,Y=y]=\sum_{x}\underbrace{P[W=w|Z=z,Y=y,X=x]}_{P[W=w|Z=z]}P[X=x|Z=z,Y=y]=P[W=w|Z=z]\underbrace{\sum_x P[X=x|Z=z,Y=y]}_{1}$$

Answer (score -1):

The question is not very clear. I am assuming that you have a Markov chain, $ \{ X_n : n \geq 0 \} $. You are interested in finding whether the chain $ \{ X_{2n} : n \geq 0 \} $ is also a Markov chain.

If that is the case, then the answer is yes. Actually $ \{ X_{kn} : n \geq 0 \} $ is a Markov chain for any integer $ k \geq 1 $. The transition probability matrix is given by $ \mathbf{P}^k $ where $ \mathbf{P}$ is the transition matrix of the original chain.

Comment: The question has an accepted answer that is two years old.