# Is subsequence (non-contiguous) of a Markov chain is also a Markov chain.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, information-theory

Let us assume $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow D$ be a Markov chain.
Can we also state that $A\rightarrow C 
 \rightarrow D$
is also a Markov chain? It intuitively feels right. Can anyone give a formal proof of it or maybe cite some resource.

Comment: How does this sequence continue? Do you occasionally "skip a state"? Or are you alternating skipping and not skipping? ETA: If skipping is periodic, then the answer is no. Suppose the parent chain simply alternates between states $1$ and $2$. Then, the child chain (the one that alternately skips and doesn't skip) goes $1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, \ldots$. Now, if you're currently in state $1$, you go to state $1$ or state $2$ with probability $1/2$ each, as you can see. But knowledge of the previous state determines the next state, so the child chain is not Markovian.

Comment: If whether you skip is governed by i.i.d. Bernoulli variables at each step of the parent chain, I think the answer is yes. ¶ This all assumes I understand what you're asking. It's possible I don't. You could probably stand to clarify your question further.

Comment: Yes, it's not periodic, rather follows i.i.d Bernoulli distribution as you pointed out.

Comment: @BrianTung can you please provide some resource to prove that it is possible to prove the statement when skip is governed by iid Bernoulli

Comment: @ASMIT: I don't have a reference at hand, I'm afraid. The exact formulation would probably depend on the exact mode of skipping. If it's Bernoulli whether you skip once or don't skip, then I imagine the child's transition matrix would look something like $qP^2 + (1-q)P$, and if it's Bernoulli whether a given state is skipped (so the number of skipped states is geometrically distributed), I imagine it would look something like $(1-q)(I-qP)^{-1}$. I'd have to sit down and convince myself to be sure, but that'd be the direction I'd look at.

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: By $A,B,C \cdots$ you mean the states or rather the successive variables (like the time-indexed values $X_1, X_2, X_3$) ?  If the latter, the question is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703039/extracting-a-smaller-markov-chain-from-a-larger-markov-chain .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your question makes sense. A Markov chain has a set of states, and transition probabilities dictating the probability of transitioning from one state to another. If you had states $A, B, C, D$ in a Markov chain you could talk about the path $A \to B \to C \to D$, but this path is not itself a Markov chain.

If you are asking if a proper subset of a Markov chain is a Markov chain, well then this also doesn't make much sense since now our transition probabilities no longer sum to $1$.

Feel free to edit your question or respond if you want further clarification.

Comment: Each random variables here has a specific value. Can't we marginalize over B to proceed further?

Comment: @BhutumBanerjee I don't follow what you are saying exactly - are you claiming that each of $A,B,C,D$ represent an event of being in a certain state in the Markov chain?

Comment: A, B, C, D are states. The question is, even if we don't consider any state in the middle, can we still call the set of remaining states following Markov property?

Comment: The translation of a Markov chain with states $A, B, C, D$ to a Markov chain with states $A, C, D$ is non-trivial. It may be the case that $A \to C$ isn't even a possible transition in your Markov chain, so how can $A \to C \to D$ be a valid path? You may be able to find a reduction to this three-state Markov chain but you would need to decide what to do with your transition probabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I got what you are saying. In the meantime the following link seems as an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703039/extracting-a-smaller-markov-chain-from-a-larger-markov-chain?rq=1

Comment: @mrepic1123 can you please point like why $A \rightarrow C$ can't be a path ?